# AngularJS wait for simple promise to be resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm really new with AngularJS and WebApi and I can't figure out how to wait for promises to be resolved.

I have a very simple application.

This is my HTML code:

```
<body ng-app="PersonApp">
<div ng-controller="PersonController">
    <div id="personTable">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="p in person">
                <td>{{ p.surname }}</td>
                <td>{{ p.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ p.birthDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}</td>
                <td>{{ p.fiscalCode }}</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" data-ng-click="edit(p)" class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
                    <button type="submit" data-ng-click="delete(p)" class="btn btn-default">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>//.................
```

My controller:

```
app.controller('PersonController', ['$scope', 'PersonApp', function ($scope, PersonApp) {
    PersonApp.getPersons($scope);
```

And finally the service:

```
app.service('PersonApp', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.getPersons = function ($scope) {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "../api/person",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }).success(function (data) {
            $scope.person = data;
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });;
    };
```

I have tried to insert promises everywhere but I really can't figure it out.

I know this is a really dumb question but I hope you have the patience to give me a simple aswer.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Where are you trying to wait for the promise to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't inject $scope into your service. The $http service will return a promise. If you modify your PersonApp service to simply return the $http promise, you can assign your $scope.person property in your controller. The code below is untested, but you will understand the basic idea.

PersonApp service

```
app.service('PersonApp', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.getPersons = function () {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "../api/person",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        });
    };
}]);
```

PersonController

```
app.controller('PersonController', function($scope, PersonApp) {
  PersonApp.getPersons().then(function(data) {
      $scope.person = data;
      console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Here is a link to a working plunker with your code (I faked the $http part since I don't have access to your service).

http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:rfqcl9AHEoJZEEJxyNn2?p=preview

Here is an article on promises with $http.

http://www.peterbe.com/plog/promises-with-$http

Comment: it's still not working...I'm sure I'm missing something stupid but I can't figure out what...

Comment: I added a plunker so you can see the code in action. I noticed you named your service to PersonApp, but in your HTML you have ng-app="PersonApp". Try renaming your service to something different (ie PersonService).

Comment: Good answer. One recommendation: you should be able to call `.success()` and `.error()` on `getPersons()` instead of simply `.then()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! Finally it's working. Thank you for your patience!